# htaccess doesn't work in server but working in localhost (Remove php extension)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wondering what's wrong with this code since last time it worked very well in both server and localhost. But now it doesn't work in server at all..

Here is my code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydomain/

# Return 404 if original request is /mydomain/index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# Rewrite /mydomain/index to /mydomain/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

My domain name is mydomain.com and localhost folder is mydomain. It works in localhost, but not on the server. What's happening?

Comment: Do you need the rewrite base (or have the correct base) on your server? Also, because you're blindly appending a .php to requests, even ones that request files that don't end with .php, you'll end up with 500 server errors.

Comment: Do you have `/mydomain/` folder on live server also?

Comment: @anubhava no, I don't have any folder here. so i should remove? Can you put an answer below if you may? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this `RewriteBase` line in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /mydomain/
```

If you don't have `mydomain` folder on live server:

```
RewriteBase /
```

`RewriteBase` represents relative path to current directory of .htaccess from `DocumentRoot`.

Full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Return 404 if original request is /mydomain/index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. As it didn't show anything at all. I assure the file index.php is from DocumentRoot.

Comment: check my update code. Make sure `.htaccess` and `.php` files are both in `DocumentRoot`. Double check what is `DocumentRoot` on live server

Answer (score 0):

Change in `httpd.conf` file (linux server : /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) for

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
# Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

if `AllowOverride None` is set, it wont reflect changes you have done in .htaccess file